# Execute groovy code in last step of current test case in modular framework without teardown script

Tags: groovy, soapui, modularity, modular, modular-design

I have a soapui framework which is modular. This means that I can execute test cases based upon business operations which are organized into different suites. With this in mind, I will need data from other test cases to use in my current test case (which is in a different suite). To accomplish this, I use a Run TestCase step in my current test case which runs the test case in suite 1 and brings the needed data into my current test case (suite 2) via project properties. After I run the current test case, I need the project properties to be cleared. I have the groovy code to do that. Here’s the issue: Since this is modular, I need to ONLY clear the project properties after the CURRENT test case is run. Using a teardown script within the test case level, isn’t working because it will always clear the project properties EVEN IF this is not the current test case being run. Meaning, my current suite is suite 2. And all the test cases in suite 2 have a teardown script that removes the project properties. When I run a test case in suite 3, and need data from a test case in suite 2, the properties will not be present due to the teardown scripts found in suite 2 (at the test case level). Again, I only need it to clear when the last step is run from the current test case, but not effect any other test cases when doing the modular execution. I hope that makes sense.

As a side note, this framework allows me to test business operations by suite for ad hoc testing. It also allows me to run a full regression from beginning to end (testing all suites in a row). I need the solution to not ruin the full regression run as well.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this I had to create a setup and tear down script at every level: Project, Suite, and Test Case.

Within the setup script, I created a variable called Is_Running. I then create an if statement which says: If “Is_Running” is NULL, then fill that variable with the name of the project, suite, or test case that is currently being executed. For example, if I’m executing at the project level, this code first checks to see if there is anything in the container Is_running, and if not it writes the project name in that variable.

Then I use the teardown script in each level which says that if the Is_Running variable is equal to the current name of what ever level I’m running, then erase the project properties. This ensures that the project properties are only erased once the current level is finished executing and not during the middle of a test (when using other suites).

For example: If I start my testing at the suite level, and I choose to run “Suite3”, the setup script will write “Suite3” in the Is_Running variable. Once Suite3 engages Suite2 to run the needed test cases, Suite2’s setup script see’s that the Is_Running variable is not null so it does NOT write it’s name to the Is_Running container. As such, the Suite2 teardown script does not erase the project properties since the name does not match. Once Suite3 has completed all it’s test steps, the teardown script sees that the Is_Running is filled with Suite3, so it deletes the project properties.

This approach allows me to run the project at any level and for the project properties to be deleted only after the current suite is finished running. I needed to know groovy well enough to do all the work mentioned above, but the approach is what I was looking for in this question. If you know of a less complicated way, please leave me a note!